# Getting json data from NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I'm trying to get data from a simple json response.

The first log shows that i find an item named access_token, however i can't use objectForKey from it, i get `[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x72de3b0`

What am i doing wrong?

```
 for(NSDictionary *item in authResponse)
    {
        NSString *s1 = @"access_token";
        NSString *s2 = [item description];

        NSLog(@"access desc: %@", [item description]);
        if([s1 isEqualToString:s2]){
            NSLog(@"Item: %@", [item objectForKey:@"access_token"]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are calling `objectForKey` on an `NSString` object, not an `NSDictionary` object.

Comment: My json object is a correct json object, how do i turn my json string into a dictionary then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `authResponse` object is an `NSDictionary` object, however it will contain many other types within it, including other `NSDictionary` objects.  You will need to be more careful about how you interpret each member:

```
for (NSObject *item in authResponse)
{
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *dictItem = (NSDictionary *)item;
        //  do thing with sub-dictionary
    }
    else if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        NSString *stringItem = (NSString *)item;
        //  do thing with string item
    }
    else if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
    {
        NSNumber *numberItem = (NSNumber *)item;
        //  do thing with number item
    }
}
```